# Erro em tempo de execução em C

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, argumento

Bem, tá compilando tudo ok, todavia, quando vou imprimir os elementos da matriz inteira tab[8][8], a qual é membro da estrutura dama, o compilador, de certa forma está atribuindo números a esta matriz, os quais não sei de onde surgiram, uma vez qua matriz deveria conter 1, -1 ou 0. Entretanto, esta armazena valores relativamente grandes, os quais desconfio que sejam posições de memória. Eu consegui contornar este empecilho, passando o endereço da estrutura dama às funções (obviamente, os parâmetros das funções também foram modificados, de forma a permitir isto). Então, nas funções, utilizei o operador de (->) em vez do de (.), uma vez que estava trabalhando com o ponteiro de uma estrutura. Os frutos oriundos disso, foi os objetivos os quais eu almejava. Todavia, não entendi porque o código abaixo não funciona como deveria.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define SIZE 8

typedef struct jogo {
    int tab[SIZE][SIZE];
    /*p[0] == constante que denota 
    o player enquanto p[1] == qt de 
    pecas que o jogador possui*/
    int player_1[2];
    int player_2[2];
} tabuleiro;

void inicializar (tabuleiro p);
void mostrar (tabuleiro p);

int main() {
    register int i, j;
    tabuleiro dama;
    inicializar(dama);
    mostrar(dama);
    return 0;
}

/*Inicializa o tabuleiro de dama*/
void inicializar (tabuleiro p) {
    register int i, j;

    p.player_1[0] = -1;
    p.player_2[0] = 1;
    p.player_1[1] = p.player_2[1] = SIZE;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) {
            if ((i == 0 && j % 2 == 1) 
            || (i == 1 && j % 2 == 0))
                p.tab[i][j] = p.player_1[0];

            else if ((i == 6 && j % 2 == 1) 
            || (i == 7 && j % 2 == 0))
                p.tab[i][j] = p.player_2[0];

            else p.tab[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

/*Apresenta o tabuleiro de dama*/
void mostrar (tabuleiro p) {
    register int i, j;

    printf("\n\n|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|\n");
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) {
            if (p.tab[i][j] == p.player_1[0])
                printf("| X ");

            else if (p.tab[i][j] == p.player_2[0])
                printf("| O ");

            else
                printf("|   ");
        }
        printf("|\n|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: E o que deveria acontecer? Está executando assim: http://ideone.com/CHrz3X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está passando uma cópia do array para a função `inicializar()`. A cópia é modificada corretamente dentro da função, porém a variável original permanece com os valores originais, que são valores aleatórios que estavam na área de memória alocada estaticamente.

Para você entender melhor, veja este exemplo usando um tipo mais simples:

```
void inc_int(int x) {
  x++;
}

void inc_intptr(int *x) {
  (*x)++;
}

int main() {
  int x = 0;

  inc_int(x);
  printf("x = %d\n", x); // imprimirá "x = 0, pois a somente a cópia será incrementada"
  inc_intptr(&x);
  printf("x = %d\n", x); // imprimirá "x = 1"

  return 0;
}
```

O problema com a função `inc_int()` é exatamente o mesmo com o seu código: ela recebe uma cópia da variável `x` e a incrementação só afeta a cópia local. Já a função `inc_intptr()` recebe o endereço da variável `x` declarada na função `main()` e quando alterada na função, afeta a variável original.

Comment: Obrigado Rubio!